# How to launch a windowed shell on a server from a web application

Tags: c#, .net, shell, web

I have a web application that should trigger an execution of a batch file on a server at some point. One of the tasks of the batch file is starting a browser on the server machine and doing some on-screen related things - that's why I need it to run in an actual window on the machine and not in a windowless hidden mode.

I tried to use `Process` class for this, but it only allowed me to run things behind the scenes. Is there a way to launch a command prompt and run a batch file, as if I did it manually, but at the same time monitor when it's done running?

Comment: in general not possible because your ASP.NET application will run server side and with no window session, even impersonating a specific user account on the IIS server box, that impersonation for your Application Pool will not create a visible / logged in user session. What is mostly done in these caees is that you do use Process.Start to execute your batch file and that you will have plenty of logging into a log file or database or windows event log so that you can monitor the batch execution from another user session.

Comment: If it was a console application, it wouldn't be a problem; it's not however. It's a batch of processes, at some point it has to record some things that are happening on the screen - and it's not possible using the `Process` trick.